# FTP access for >1 user with same account?

Tags: ftp, connection, accounts

I'm creating an iPhone app which is basically a breakout game, but you can create your own levels and upload/download stuff! It's working well... sort of.

My game uses a single account for whoever has it installed, and this connects to my FTP and downloads the level files. Problem is, I can't log in on two devices at once as my FTP server only supports 1 login at a time from my account.

So, my question is, is it technically possible to connect to an FTP from more than one location using the same account, simultaneously? If so, can anyone point me in the way of a cheap (or free, free is better!) host that can offer this?

Many thanks,
- Javawag

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible for a FTP server to accept more than one connections at the same time using the same account, but we really can't tell you anything more if you don't tell at least which FTP server are you using and on which operating system.

Comment: Otherwise "anonymous" logins to FTP wouldn't work...

Comment: That's good news! Well I don't actually own a server, I'm using a free host (I know, I know, this is total blasphemy on this site!) at www.hostultra.com. Chose it because I get unlimited traffic and storage, just a 10meg file size limit. I'm not sure which OS they use at that site, I don't think it says.

Comment: @Bart, of course! Totally didn't think of it like that - anonymous is just another user account isn't it!